# how to check and close if an excel file is already open in java

Tags: java, io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: Check if file is already open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390592/java-check-if-file-is-already-open)

I am making a swing utility in which i am creating and using a excel sheet by Apache poi.
If the file is already opened while i m trying to access it it throws an exception like some other process is using this excel file. So all i want is to check if that excel file is already opened and if yes then close it.

Comment: Do you want to close the *other* program or *your* program?

Comment: i want to close the excel file

Comment: If another program holds the file open, then you need to either shut down that program or instruct the program to close the file. Which of those two are you after?

Comment: by other program it means OS i think. Overall i just opened the target excel by just double click on that and so i got this exception in java that 
"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" 
PS my bad its process not program  :)

Answer (score 2):

Did you do some Google search on this topic: Here is some I came up with

- [Java: Check if file is already open](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1390592/851432)
- [check if a file is already open before trying to delete it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8634377/851432)
- [checking that an excel file is already opened by another application](http://www.coderanch.com/t/438783/Streams/java/checking-excel-file-already-opened)

I am copying the answer from the first question on stackoverflow here:

```
File file = new File(fileName);
FileChannel channel = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw").getChannel();
// Get an exclusive lock on the whole file
FileLock lock = channel.lock();
try {
    lock = channel.tryLock();
    // Ok. You get the lock
} catch (OverlappingFileLockException e) {
    // File is open by someone else
} finally {
    lock.release();
}
```

Hope this will be of help.

Comment: FileLock is platform dependent & is not guaranteed to work (I've had my fair share of this not working)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this:

```
File file = new File(pathToFile);
if (file.canRead()) {
  <do whatever you are doing with the file>
}
```

Comment: no this is not the solution. this only tells you whether the file can be read or not. it return true in both cases 1. file is open already 
2. file is close.