# How to know whether a particular file is still opened or closed using java

Tags: java, file-io

I have a scenario where i have used to open a file using the java commands in following steps

a) creating File object for the location of file

```
File f = new File(filePath);
```

b) then using system application (like Excel) to open the file

```
Desktop desktop = null;
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
}
try {
    desktop.open(f);
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Now I want to get informed in the program when this file is closed by the window application. Is there any mechanism to know whether the opened file is still open or closed by the application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Check if file is already open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390592/java-check-if-file-is-already-open)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt whether you will get a definite solution for this.

you can look at this thread

[Java: Check if file is already open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390592/java-check-if-file-is-already-open)

The main problem is, the fileLock is dependent on file system of the OS.