# Write Lock in Java

Tags: java, locking

I have a file say `text.csv` from which my java programs tries to read/write.

Is there a way in Java to detect if this file is opened for writing when the file has been opened by some user by "double clicking"? If so , how? I'm looking for this kind of code:

```
if(isOpenForWrite(File file){
//say text.csv is already opened ...
}
```

Any helpful documentation or other resources is welcome.

Comment: http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ314_030.htm

Comment: @StanislavL Does that locking interfere with other processes accessing files?

Comment: @Kunal Krishna Have you read this 

"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390592/java-check-if-file-is-already-open"

Comment: @StanislavL FileLock is made for suncing acces inside java, it can't detect if the file is locked with some other application

Answer (score 0):

Best way to check this is checking if you can rename the file

```
String fileName = "C:\\Text.xlsx";
File file = new File(fileName);

// try to rename the file with the same name
File sameFileName = new File(fileName);

if(file.renameTo(sameFileName)){
    // if the file is renamed
    System.out.println("file is closed");    
}else{
    // if the file didnt accept the renaming operation
    System.out.println("file is opened");
}
```

or use Apache Common IO library

Comment: Note that the rename can work and _then_ a user could open the file.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis same can happen with any check, so i don't think this is a problem of implementation.

Comment: I just don't think it will be very reliable.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis that's still the only way that working for me when checking MS Office files for being opened. Only other way is Commons IO but using library only for this seems strange for me. Especially if you can do the same with 4 lines of code.

Comment: How often do you loop to check?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i was checking it every time i needed to export data to file. And it's not in loop, it checks every time we need to edit file.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the FileChannel.lock to do this.

```
try { // Get a file channel for the file 
    File file = new File("text.csv");
    FileChannel channel = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw").getChannel();

    // Blocks until it can retrieve the lock. 
    FileLock lock = channel.lock(); 
    // Try acquiring the lock without blocking. 
    // lock is null or exception if the file is already locked. 

    try { 
        lock = channel.tryLock();
    } catch (OverlappingFileLockException e){}


    lock.release(); // Close the file 
    channel.close();
} catch (Exception e) { 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Source : [Java: Check if file is already open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390592/java-check-if-file-is-already-open)

Use this i found this in above commanded link

```
    boolean isFileUnlocked = false;
    try {
     org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.touch(yourFile);
    isFileUnlocked = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
    isFileUnlocked = false;
    }

    if(isFileUnlocked){
    // Do stuff you need to do with a file that is NOT locked.
    } else {
    // Do stuff you need to do with a file that IS locked
    }
```