# Want to define state-sequence of processes in the property file in Java

Tags: java, file-io, directory, nio

I am planning to build a program which keeps on looking the directory, and if any new file comes then it'll notify me. But I don't want to use Watch Service API. Is there any other simple logic to do the same? without using any third party API or library?

Comment: Just curious, why not use the WatchService? And why ask the question regarding same thing multiple times (just an attempt to gain repo points??)?  Question that you already asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34553881/how-to-check-whether-files-are-there-or-not-continuously-in-java

Comment: Here my question is about state sequence. Suppose, I want to change the sequence from 1-2-3-4 to 1-2-4-3 then without changing in the code, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The [Watch Service API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) is the simplest and most efficient way to do this, which is why it exists.

You can however, poll the directory and look for changes. This has some down sides.

- It is hard to detect all possible changes.
- It can be really inefficient and create a lot of garbage if you do this regularly or have a lot of files or both.
- It can be error prone if you haven't implemented this before.

> Is there any other simple logic to do the same?

Repeatedly call

```
File dir = new File(directoryName);
// note: creates a lot of garbage even if nothing changed.
File[] files = dir.listFiles(); 
if (files != null) {
    // check for changes.
```