# Monitor which Java process and which class/method accesses a specifc file

Tags: java, file, monitor

I was wondering if there is a way to monitor the file system in Java.

Suppose the following

```
C:\Users\foobar\Desktop\notes.txt
```

I'd like to monitor which Java process accesses this file and when.  The end goal is to return the Class and if possible the method.

Pseudocode example showing what I want to do

```
public/private class FileReader {
  private void getFileContents(String fileName) throws Exception {
  ...
    FileReader fileReader = Znew FileReader(fileName);

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }
 ...   
}
```

Separate unrelated Class

```
public class Monitor {
  ...thread...
  onFileAccessed() {
    System.out.println(processID);
    System.out.println(jarName);
    System.out.println(className);
    System.out.println(methodName);
  }
  ...thread...
}
```

tyia!

Comment: Have you had a look at [Watching a Directory for Changes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452527/watching-a-directory-for-changes-in-java

Comment: I would write a wrapper around the WatchService.

Comment: This has nothing to do with watching a directory for changes. He wants to know which method of which java process accesses the file. Does jconsole does what you need? Or can you modify the java applications or enable JMX? If not then you can ask the OS which process accesses the file but it wont give you the method.

Comment: Isn't it better to monitor such a stuff on OS level? E.g. lsof on linux or similar for Windows?

Comment: Are you running on Solaris, MacOS, or any other OS with a fully-functional and stable dtrace implementation?  If so, dump the user-space stack of the process that touched your file and parse the output.