# How to upload a files in dir to S3 when files are continuesly getting written in dir

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So I am uploading all files from a dir into S3 using `TransferManager` 
and I am able to upload also .
But my issue in the same dir file are getting written also.
So how do i call that method to write into S3 .
Do i have to call that method on fixed interval ?
Please suggest what could be the best way to call that method.

```
public void uploadDir(Path strFile,String strFileName){

        ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
        for (Path path : strFile) {
            files.add(new File(path.toString()));
        }

        TransferManager xfer_mgr = TransferManagerBuilder.standard().build();
        try {
            MultipleFileUpload xfer = xfer_mgr.uploadFileList(bucketName,strFileName, new File("."), files);
            //XferMgrProgress.showTransferProgress(xfer);
            //XferMgrProgress.waitForCompletion(xfer);
        } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getErrorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The best thing to do would be to listen to changes in that directory and upload the changes objects to S3 only when a change happens. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452527/watching-a-directory-for-changes-in-java

Comment: @MatthewPope yes I am doing that but files are keeps on coming so how do we control the event

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re asking then. Can you try to clarify your question?

Comment: @Anupam if I understood correctly, files are continuously getting written on your local directory, you're having a service that keeps listening to the directory, but problem is, file listener is picking files even before completely written by the file creators, is that accurate? please modify the question if not the case

Answer (score 0):

Couple of solutions, you could try any, based on your need.

**Solution 1:-** For scanrio like your, instead of time interval, you should be using `fileAge`.

> FileAge:when the file was last modified, this common concept used by file Poller either local directory or remote directory.

So think like your files takes max. 20 seconds in writing, then only pull files older then 20s or more.

**Solution 2:-**

> Other way is ask your clients, the program generating files to use some extension say .tmp, when file writing completed, ask them to convert it to actual file extension and modify your program to skip files with extension .tmp.
>   e.g While writing `abc.jpg` to `abc.jpg.tmp`, when files writing completed, then rename it to `abc.jpg`.

Hope this helps.