# Deleting a file, opended by an external application, after closing it

Tags: java, file-io

I'm creating a pdf file in my java program.

After having it created to a specified Path, I'm opening it with the user's standard application.

```
File myFile = new File("F:/test.pdf");
Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);
```

My standard application for pdf files is for example Adobe Reader - so Adobe Reader opens up and displays the file. - So far so good.

Is there any way to delete this "test.pdf" after I close the file/my Adobe Reader?

Comment: does Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile) work in a blocking way? Which means, it stops execution of your application until you close your default pdf reader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following link:
[Java: Check if file is already open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390592/java-check-if-file-is-already-open)

Run an infinite loop after you open the loop, as mentioned in the above thread, verify and close the file accordingly.

Thanks,
JK

Answer (score 1):

You can create the file in the temp directory, so you will not have to worry about removing it.

To create a file in the temp directory you should use the `File.createTempFile` method.

Comment: The code implies that this on Windows, which won't automatically clean up its temporary directory.