# java.io.IOException: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion - when using IOUtils.copyLarge() in Windows

Tags: java, windows, file-io

The issue is stemming from the specificied line of code in this try block:

```
try {
            fInputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
#thisLine   byteCount += IOUtils.copyLarge(fInputStream, fOutputStream);
            fileCount++;
    }
```

The stack-trace looks like this:

```
java.io.IOException: The process cannot access the file because another 
process has locked a portion 
 of the file 
        at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method) 
        at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:233) 
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1719) 
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1696)
```

This seems to be a Windows-specific issue. Is there some File I/O best practice(s) specific to Windows that I might be missing?

Comment: Any process or thread accessing the same file ?

Comment: @primitiveType Of course there is. That's what the exception says.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved that issue by passing earlier created `fileChannel` object.

```
FileChannel fileChannel = FileChannel.open(path, 
                   StandardOpenOption.READ,StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
```

then I created `InputStream` object like this:

```
Channels.newInputStream(fileChannel);
```

It worked and no more exception occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Check if another process is accessing the same file. On Windows follow this post to figure it out -> https://superuser.com/questions/399659/how-can-i-identify-what-application-is-using-a-given-file

It should work as soon as no other process is accessing the same file.

To make sure you can actually access the file consider reading the following topic -> [Java: Check if file is already open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390592/java-check-if-file-is-already-open)