# How to check file is opened or not in java is not working

Tags: java, file, filechannel, filelock, apache-commons-io

I try to check file is opened or not in java using following examples . I use Apache Commons IO library...

```
boolean isFileUnlocked = false;
try {
    org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.touch(yourFile);
    isFileUnlocked = true;
} catch (IOException e) {
    isFileUnlocked = false;
}

if(isFileUnlocked){
    // Do stuff you need to do with a file that is NOT locked.
} else {
    // Do stuff you need to do with a file that IS locked
}
```

This brings me a wrong formation . When I am not opened the exact file, this show me the file has opened. If file is not opened, result is false and this cannot be possible .

Other example is here,

```
public boolean isFileOpened(File file){
  boolean res = false;
  FileChannel channel = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw").getChannel();
  // Get an exclusive lock on the whole file
  FileLock lock = channel.lock();
  try {
      //The file is not already opened 
      lock = channel.tryLock();
   } catch (OverlappingFileLockException e) {
    // File is open by someone else
    res = true;
   } finally {
    lock.release();
   }
  return res;
}
```

This also brings me incorrect information.

I get these examples from here [Java: Check if file is already open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390592/java-check-if-file-is-already-open)

Now my problem is how could I check file is opened or not in java correctly ?

Thank you.

Comment: What does 'the exact file' mean? As opposed to what?

Comment: @EJP : The file I used in parameters