# how to check if certain Microsoft word document is closed

Tags: java, ms-word

If user is writing in a word file(eg: `abc.docx`) and he finishes working and closes this file, I want to get its status that `abc.docx` is been close is there any way to find out using java 
i am just passing the path of  the docx file

```
File file = new File("abc.docx");
                    log.info("file {} exits {}",file,file.exists());
```

i want to get the status either file is opened or closed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if file is already open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390592/check-if-file-is-already-open)

Comment: Can you post some code that you have tried?

Comment: i have added the code also the link given above does not work for me

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but... When I file is open in Word, Word creates a "temp" file in the same folder where that file is saved. When the file is closed (normally, not through a crash) the temp file is removed. A temp file begins with a tilde ( ~ ) plus dollar sign ( $ ). For example, `~$tiveX_ComboBox.docm` is the temp file for `ActiveX_ComboBox.docm`. Theoretically, you could check for the presence of such a file before and immediately after opening a document and, when it disappears again, the file is closed. Or can Java monitor events in the Word application?